# Specify Style from App.Resources to Theme file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, themes

Here's a simple thing with which I am struggling with :
I have a style specified in my App.Resources

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDock:PaneToolWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

I would Like to move this into my theme file by trying something like this.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey {x:Type DockManager:PaneToolWindow}, defaultBackground}" Color="Red" PresentationOptions:Freeze="true" />
```

Of course I am doing something terribly wrong here, My intention is to have all floating windows a default style.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a solid color Brush? The way you had it initially would have worked fine if placed in your custom XAML file.

Just put

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDock:PaneToolWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

...in your style file.